# icCube Schema Refresh Time

Tags: mdx, olap, iccube

I'm using icCube Web reports and I'd like to display the refresh time of the cube but could not find how to do it.
I guess there's a way using a dedicated MDX statement but could not find any reference in the documentation. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MDX function [SchemaRefreshTime](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SchemaRefreshTime.php) gives you this information. So you can use a "Simple Table" widget with a "Plain MDX" request:

```
with 
  member [Measures].[Schema Refresh Time] as SchemaRefreshTime(), 
         FORMAT_STRING = "j:HH'h'mm"

select [Measures].[Schema Refresh Time] on 0 from [Sales]
```

The FORMAT_STRING is using a Java [simple date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).